# Where to ask opinion based question?

Tags: support

I have a question like the following:

> I plan to build a webapplication and think about making it a mostly clientside app. Of course I gonna need to fetch data from my server for userdata etc.
>   Now my question is, should I render the data on the client or should I send the data as rendered HTML back to the browser?
>   PS: The server is probably a `raspberry pi 2` and the server environment is node.js. The browser will be modern and on good clients.

For me this question is very opinion based and I am unsure if it will get closed.

So, is it okay to ask this question here or on Stack Overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design Review: on-topic or not?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/design-review-on-topic-or-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of your question is fairly close to being a good Programmers question. It would definitely be off-topic on StackOverflow, but it should be on-topic here.

You do need to add some more detail though. In its current state it *might* get closed as "primarily opinion-based" or "unclear what you're asking", since we'd have to guess a lot of details about your application to come up with an answer. Try telling us a little bit about what this data is, what kind of "rendering" process you're referring to (it's obviously not actual rendering if it can be done by the server), whether you expect to support multiple frontends for this data (e.g. a mobile and desktop site), whether 3rd party integration is expected to be a thing, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This question would be closed as "primarily opinion-based" because each option could be the correct one based on programmer preference.

I am not aware of any Stack Exchange site on which this question would be on-topic.